# how to sort in XSL transforming xml to html

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

the xml file is given like this and i want to tranfer them into a html form:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bncDoc>
<stext>
<div>
<u who="PS6H7">  
<s n="3">
    <w c5="AV0" hw="well" pos="ADV">Has</w>
    <c c5="PUN">, </c>
    <w c5="AJ0" hw="good" pos="ADJ">Well </w>
    <w c5="NN1" hw="afternoon" pos="SUBST">afternoon</w>
    <c c5="PUN">, </c>
    <w c5="PNI" hw="everybody" pos="PRON">everybody</w>
    <c c5="PUN">, </c>
    <w c5="PNP" hw="i" pos="PRON">I </w>
    <w c5="VVB" hw="think" pos="VERB">think </w>
    <w c5="PNP" hw="we" pos="PRON">we</w>
    <w c5="VHD" hw="have" pos="VERB">'d </w>
    <w c5="AV0" hw="well" pos="ADV">better </w>
    <w c5="VVI" hw="get" pos="VERB">get </w>
    <w c5="VVN" hw="start" pos="VERB">started</w>
    <c c5="PUN">.</c>
</s>
</u>

<u who="asdfgg">
<s n="4">
    <w c5="PNP" hw="we" pos="PRON">has </w>
    <w c5="VVD" hw="look" pos="VERB">Well </w>
    <w c5="AV0" hw="so" pos="ADV">so </w>
    <w c5="AJ0" hw="thin" pos="ADJ">thin </w>
    <w c5="PRP" hw="on" pos="PREP">on </w>
    <w c5="AT0" hw="the" pos="ART">the </w>
    <w c5="NN1" hw="ground" pos="SUBST">ground</w>
    <c c5="PUN">, </c>
    <w c5="PNP" hw="i" pos="PRON">I </w>
    <w c5="VVD" hw="think" pos="VERB">thought </w>
    <w c5="PNP" hw="we" pos="PRON">we</w>
    <w c5="VM0" hw="would" pos="VERB">'d </w>
    <w c5="VVI" hw="sit" pos="VERB">sit </w>
    <w c5="CJC" hw="and" pos="CONJ">and </w>
    <w c5="VVI" hw="wait" pos="VERB">wait </w>
    <w c5="CJC" hw="and" pos="CONJ">and </w>
    <w c5="VVI" hw="see" pos="VERB">see </w>
    <w c5="CJS" hw="if" pos="CONJ">if </w>
    <w c5="PNI" hw="everyone" pos="PRON">everyone</w>
    <w c5="VBZ" hw="be" pos="VERB">'s </w>
    <w c5="VVG-AJ0" hw="come" pos="VERB">coming</w>
    <c c5="PUN">, </c>
    <w c5="CJC" hw="but" pos="CONJ">but </w>
    <w c5="UNC" hw="erm" pos="UNC">erm </w>
    <w c5="PNP" hw="we" pos="PRON">we</w>
    <w c5="VM0" hw="will" pos="VERB">'ll </w>
    <w c5="VHI" hw="have" pos="VERB">have </w>
    <w c5="TO0" hw="to" pos="PREP">to </w>
    <w c5="VVI" hw="get" pos="VERB">get </w>
    <w c5="VVN" hw="start" pos="VERB">started </w>
    <w c5="AV0" hw="anyway" pos="ADV">anyway</w>
    <c c5="PUN">.</c>
</s>
</u>
</div> 
</stext> 
</bncDoc>
```

and i have finished the xsl document like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="bncDoc/stext/div/u/*/w">
        <xsl:for-each select=".">
            <xsl:variable name="selectedWord" ><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="countNumber" select="count(//w[contains(., $selectedWord)]) "/>
            <tr>
                <td id="row1">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </td>
                <td id="row2">
                    <xsl:element name="number"> <xsl:value-of select="$countNumber"/></xsl:element>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h2>Frequency Table</h2>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
                        <th>Word</th>
                        <th>Show up Times</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="bncDoc/stext/div/u/*/w"></xsl:apply-templates>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the outcoming result is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9le1I.jpg)

i want to sort the result based on the "Show up Times" row, but it seems not working, is there any solutions to solve this problem?

Comment: Your `<xsl:for-each select=".">` is completely useless. You can remove it without any change to the result.

Comment: You can see a simple sorting example here - http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2002/07/03/transform.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i want to sort the result based on the "Show up Times" row

You cannot sort by something that exists only in the output tree. You must repeat the count for the purposes of sort: change this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="bncDoc/stext/div/u/*/w"></xsl:apply-templates>
```

to:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="bncDoc/stext/div/u/*/w">
    <xsl:sort select="count(//w[contains(., current())])" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

---

P.S. I suspect what you really want to do here is *group* the words - see: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html